# Outlook Signature Broken in Entourage

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, html, entourage, email-signature

Some of our company uses Windows with Outlook 2010, and the rest use Mac with Entourage.

When our standard signature line is included in an email that goes to Entourage, the result does not display correctly.  It appears that Entourage is mangling the HTML.  My working theory is that Entourage encounters inline CSS styles it does not know about and stops processing styles, but I'm really not sure.

**Question: How can I enter a signature into Outlook 2010 that will render correctly in Entourage?**

For example, can I specify somehow the exact HTML to use?

Here's an example of how the HTML is being changed.

Original on Outlook, as received by another Outlook client:

```
<span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Century Gothic","sans-serif";
color:#1785C5'>My Company<br>
</span></b><span class=apple-style-span><span style='font-size:9.0pt;
font-family:"Century Gothic","sans-serif";color:#666666'>123 Main St.</span></span><span
class=apple-style-span><span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Century Gothic","sans-serif";
color:#AFAFAF'>&nbsp;</span></span><span class=apple-style-span><span
style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Century Gothic","sans-serif";color:#666666'>Suite
100</span></span>
```

Note the use of spans, color #1785C5 and color #666666.

Same original email, as displayed in an Entourage client:

```
<span style='font-size:9.0pt;font-family:"Century Gothic","sans-serif";
mso-fareast-font-family:"Times New Roman"'><br>
<span style='color:#656565'>My Company<br>
123 Main St Suite 100<br>
</span>
```

Note the use of br tags rather than spans, and the color #656565.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where the font family was not being rendered and kept defaulting to Times. After seeing your post I specified the mso-fareast-font-family: style with the fonts I wanted and found Entourage will render the font appropriately e.g.
font-family: "Century Gothic","sans-serif";
mso-fareast-font-family: "Century Gothic","sans-serif";